# Dynamic Time Warping Classification using tslearn

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, classification, dtw

I am having some problem while implementing DTW classification with tslearn library . Specially while training the model.

I have multiple time series data of variable length and multiple dimensions. At the very first step what I did was to upload the multiple files into a list of dataframes for visualization . Then I converted those list of dataframes filtering out all the columns into numpy arrays . Splitted into train and test and then tried to train the model with dtw as the distance metrics .

I am not sure where I am missing out something because I have facing a **ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**

I tried to flatten my numpy array and feed it to the model, I tried to reshape it (-1,1), I tried to change the dtype into float but nothing works out (It seems I am missing onto something)

Below are the snippet of my code I am sharing :

**These are the multiple dataframes from the time series in the list which I further reduced to just using one column from the entire list**

```
from tslearn.neighbors import KNeighborsTimeSeriesClassifier
from tslearn.metrics import dtw
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np          
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

print(timeseries())
     OUTPUT : /
    time          IR         TC  \
         0      0.006361   111.089076  36.395268   
         1      0.012713   108.589543  36.389164   
         2      0.018961   107.910312  36.387853   
         3      0.025192   107.363165  36.389093   
         4      0.031445    106.785048  36.381344   
         ...         ...    ...      ...      ...    
         
         
                         p         TS    IRtime  
         0        4.318834  44.917064  09:15:15  
         1        4.522443  45.028859  09:15:15  
         2        4.485727  45.021396  09:15:15  
         3        4.518629  45.351248  09:15:15  
         4        4.513145  45.645672  09:15:15  
         ...           ...        ...       ...  
        
        [9589 rows x 10 columns],
                    time          IR         TC  \
         0      0.006373      75.354227  38.953333   
         1      0.012679      74.493989  38.968091   
         2      0.018946      76.143107  38.969021   
         3      0.025177      77.940211  38.962893   
         4      0.031404      79.705939  38.965134   
         ...         ...    ...      ...      ...    
         
                         p         TS    IRtime  
         0        4.519344  33.986072  09:16:23  
         1        4.551769  34.114317  09:16:23  
         2        4.522443  34.183959  09:16:23  
         3        4.535080  34.111575  09:16:23  
         4        4.532219  34.109334  09:16:23  
         ...           ...        ...       ...  
        
         
         [8376 rows x 10 columns],

ts = timeseries()
[i.drop(columns=['time','IRtime','value','value.1','value.2','value.3','IR','TS','p'],inplace = True) for i in ts]
X = []
for i in ts:
    i = i.values
    X.append(i.flatten())
y = labels()['target'].values 
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
print(X_train) 
 O> [array([36.39526801, 36.38916449, 36.38785319, ..., 39.40492146,
        39.40108292, 40.43806081]),
 array([38.95333278, 38.96809089, 38.96902072, ..., 40.1875067 ,
        40.1795912 , 40.18588545]),
 array([39.6719503 , 39.67082973, 39.66928001, ..., 40.43901449,
        40.43760782, 40.43856149]),
 array([39.82344148, 39.81049535, 39.80937479, ..., 40.63313492,
        40.64379223, 40.62316902]),
 array([40.0663662 , 40.07699967, 40.06004811, ..., 40.88702689,
        40.89880477, 40.89603912]),

# My X_train and X_test looks exactly the same 
 print(y_train)

O>array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]

knn = KNeighborsTimeSeriesClassifier(n_neighbors=2,metric =dtw)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

Error : 
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**My Questions are as follows :**

**Q1. How can I fix this problem ?**

**Q2: Are their any other libraries that does the following calculating the distance matrix and classifying it ? (I tried dtai too to find the distance matrix but didn't understood how can I use that matrix in my classification because I was facing same problem when I was trying to fit the model)**

**Q3. I want to implement multidimensional (multiple feature) in dynamic time warping i.e IR,TC,TS together and do the classification . Are there some methods which we can use to make it work ?**

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Q1, it may be worth using `tslearn`'s [`to_time_series_dataset`](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/utils/tslearn.utils.to_time_series_dataset.html#tslearn.utils.to_time_series_dataset) utility function in order to get your dataset into the appropriate format for the `KNeighborsTimeSeriesClassifier`.

Regarding Q2 and Q3, I have recently published a stable version of my package [Sequentia](https://github.com/eonu/sequentia) which provides sequence classifiers using dynamic time warping and hidden Markov models. The package follows an sklearn-like interface, and the DTW-kNN classifier supports multivariate sequences with varying durations. The DTW-kNN classifier works by computing a distance matrix of DTW distances between the training sequences and the new sequences being classified, then runs the kNN algorithm using that distance matrix. These predictions can be multi-processed, and use fast pure C compiled functions from [`dtaidistance`](https://github.com/wannesm/dtaidistance) for DTW computations.

Below is a basic example fitting a DTW-kNN classifier on two-dimensional sequences with different lengths in classes 0/1. `fit`/`predict` functions expect the input to be all of your sequences concatenated into one array, and the lengths should be provided separately.

```py
import numpy as np
from sequentia.models import KNNClassifier

# Sequences
X = np.array([
    # Sequence 1 - Length 3
    [1.2 , 7.91],
    [1.34, 6.6 ],
    [0.92, 8.08],
    # Sequence 2 - Length 5
    [2.11, 6.97],
    [1.83, 7.06],
    [1.54, 5.98],
    [0.86, 6.37],
    [1.21, 6.6 ]
])

# Sequence lengths
lengths = np.array([3, 5])

# Sequence classes
y = np.array([0, 1])

# Create and fit a classifier
clf = KNNClassifier(k=1, use_c=True, n_jobs=-1).fit(X, y, lengths)

# Predict classes for sequences
y_pred = clf.predict(X, lengths)

# Calculate accuracy
acc = clf.score(X, y, lengths)
```